# What is the JavaScript equivalent of the below jQuery code snippet?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code works fine with jquery, however, when I try to convert the same to javascript using addEventListener, I don't get the same output. Here is the jQuery code snippet:

```js
    (function($){ 

        $( document.body ).on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
            console.log('EVENT: added_to_cart');
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Could you show us your attempt with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. You're listening for a non-standard event, so the code which creates that event is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This will work. just create empty `html` file with script section and put this code there.

```
// Equivalent of (function($) {})
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

    // Equivalent of $(document.body).on('added_to_cart')
    document.body.addEventListener('added_to_cart', function() {
        console.log('EVENT: added_to_cart');
    });
});

// dispatching part
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('added_to_cart'));
}, 3000);
```

Comment: No need to wrap the code in a `DOMContentLoaded` listener. `document.body` is always available.

Comment: Yes you are right (because of `document.body`). But I tried to write the same code `line-by-line` as it is in the question

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter in JS:

```js
document.body.addEventListener('added_to_cart', function() {
    console.log('EVENT: added_to_cart');
});
setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('added_to_cart'));
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I am trying the same, however, it only works with the jQuery approach.

Comment: With the amount of information you provide, nobody will be able to help you then.

Comment: document.body.addEventListener('added_to_cart', function() {
    console.log('EVENT: added_to_cart');
});

^^ with the above Vanilla JS approach, it shows nothing in the console, other than that 'added_to_cart' is a custom event which is dispatched when any item is added to cart, and also when I am using the mentioned jQuery code, the console.log is executed as expected, not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Exactly how are you dispatching the custom event?

Comment: Yeah, this is working when I dispatch the event from the same file, but ideally it should work even when dispatched from a different js file.

Comment: @NeerajMalwal from another file does not matter..... If that is not working, then you have a different problem.